# Perl -e and print $_

Tags: perl

I have a loop similar to :

```
if ( -e "$hash->{'key'}/filename" ) {
    print $_
}
```

I though $_ would refer to the argument of '-e' but that is not the case. Any special variable I could use here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign to a variable inside the test:

```
if ( -e (my $_ = "...")) {
  print;
}
```

`-e` will test on `$_` if no argument is given, but it does not assign its argument to `$_`. To learn more about filetest operators, read the [`perlfunc` entry](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html).